# Laravel: Migration not working due to errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to execute a migration of two seperate tables including relationships:

**First table:**

```
public function up()
{

Schema::create('Gerecht', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('Gerechtcode');
$table->string('Gerecht', 20);

$table->foreign('Gerechtcode')->references('Gerechtcode')->on('Subgerecht');
});

}
```

**Second table:**

```
public function up()
{

Schema::create('Subgerecht', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('SubgerechtCode');
$table->string('Gerechtcode',3 );
$table->string('Subgerecht', 25);

$table->foreign('Gerechtcode')->references('Gerechtcode')->on('Gerecht');
});

}
```

But it gives me an error as followed:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `excellent-taste-db`.`#sql-59c_7d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `Gerecht` add constraint `gerecht_gerechtcode_foreign` foreign key (`Gerechtcode`) references `Subgerecht` (`Gerechtcode`))
```

Comment: Could  you please try with this once hope it works $table->integer('Gerechtcode') ?

Comment: In case of foreign keys, the referenced and referencing fields must have exactly the same data type. Please check that too.

Answer (score 1):

On your **first table**:

```
public function up()
{

Schema::create('Gerecht', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('Gerechtcode');
$table->string('Gerecht', 20);

$table->foreign('Gerechtcode')->references('Gerechtcode')->on('Subgerecht');
});

}
```

You are using the the primary key (Gerechtcode) to references on the other table. That is not possible. I think it will work if you change the **first table** to:

```
public function up()
{

Schema::create('Gerecht', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('Gerechtcode');
$table->unsignedInteger('SubgerechtCode');
$table->string('Gerecht', 20);

$table->foreign('SubgerechtCode')->references('Gerechtcode')->on('Subgerecht');
});

}
```

And the **second table** to:

```
public function up()
{

Schema::create('Subgerecht', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('SubgerechtCode');
$table->string('Subgerecht', 25);
});

}
```

In that way you have a one-to-many relationship that can be handled in Laravel. But your code does not allow me to understand your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You migration is incorrectly formed. Firstly a primary key and a foreign must be of the same type, in your case since the primary key is using laravel's `increments` method, the foreign key should be an `unsigned integer`. Secondly you're setting the primary in the first table as a foreign in the same table which is completely wrong.

You migrations should look like this

**First table**

```
public function up()
{

Schema::create('Gerecht', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('Gerechtcode');
$table->string('Gerecht', 20);

});

}
```

**Second table**

```
public function up()
{

Schema::create('Subgerecht', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('SubgerechtCode');
$table->unsignedInteger('Gerechtcode');
$table->string('Subgerecht', 25);

$table->foreign('Gerechtcode')->references('Gerechtcode')->on('Gerecht');
});

}
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) for more info.